# Find $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n$

Tags: limits

Suppose $f\colon[0,\infty)\to(0,1)$ is a continuous function. Define the sequence $a_n$ :
$$a_1 = 1, \quad a_{n+1}=\int_0^{a_n} f(x)\,\mathrm dx$$

Then find $$\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n.$$

I just know $a_n$ goes to zero when $n$ goes to $\infty$ intuitively.

But how can I solve this more strict and in more detail?

Comment: $a_{n+1}=\int_{0}^{a_n}f<\int_{0}^{a_n}=a_n$. Therefore the sequence is decreasing. Since it is bounded from below by $0$ it must have a limit $a$. Taking limits in the recurrence equation we get that $a=\int_{0}^{a}f$. If $a>0$ then the same strict inequality as above ($a=\int_{0}^{a}f<a$) is produced. Therefore, $a=0$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since $0<f(x)<1$, note that $a_n$ is decreasing and bounded below by $0$. So it's convergent. Say $\lim a_n=L$. Taking the limit to your equality, you have $$L=\int _0^L f(x)\,\mathrm dx.$$ 
Now, $f(x)<1$, convince yourself that if $L>0$ then  $L=\int _0^L f(x)\,\mathrm dx<\int _0^L 1\,\mathrm dx=L$. A contradiction. So $L=0$.

Answer (score 1):

First note that, since $f$ is continuous and $f<1$ , we have $a_{n+1}<a_n$ for all $n\in\mathbb N$. In particular, all $0\le a_n\le 1$ for all $n$.

Define the map $F:[0,1]\to [0,1]: x\mapsto \int_0^x f(\tau)\,\mathrm d\tau$.

Since $f$ is continuous on $[0,1]$, it attains it maximum on $[0,1]$ by the [Extreme value Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extreme_value_theorem). Thus, there exists $c<1$ such that $f(x)\le c$ for all $x\in[0,1]$.

Similarly, there is a constant $\widetilde c>0$ such that $f>\widetilde c$ on $[0,1]$. Thus, $x=0$ is the only fixed point of $F$.

Note that $0<F'(x)=f(x)\le c$ for $x\in[0,1]$. Thus, $F$ is a contraction. By the [Banach fixed point Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach_fixed-point_theorem), any sequence given by $a_1\in[0,1]$, $a_{n+1} := F(a_n)$ will thus converge to the only fixed point of $F$, in this case $0$.